# Работа с буфером обмена

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте! Не могли бы вы подсказать, каким образом можно осуществить контроль содержания буфера обмена? То есть программа должна иметь возможность работы со все время обновляемым содержанием clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

Есть [несколько опций](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649016(v=vs.85).aspx#dataxchg_Monitoring_Clipboard_Contents), в зависимости от операционной системы. Для Windows Vista можно создать слушатель, который будет отслеживать изменения в буфере обмена и получать сообщения при наличии таковых.

Подписка и отписка делаются с помощью функций `AddClipboardFormatListener` и `RemoveClipboardFormatListener` соответственно. Приходящие сообщения называются `WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE`.

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться кроссплатформенным фреймвором Qt.

```
class ClipboardSpy
    : QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
  public:
    ClipboardSpy()
    {
        connect(QGuiApplication::clipboard(), SIGNAL(changed(QClipboard::Mode)),
                SLOT(onClipboardChanged(QClipboard::Mode)));
    }
  private slots:
    void onClipboardChanged(QClipboard::Mode mode)
    {
        if (mode != QClipboard::Clipboard) return;
        QString clipboardText = QGuiApplication::clipboard()->text();
        // обработка ...
    }
};
```

С помощью этого объекта можно отслеживать изменения системного буфера обмена. Пока он жив, он будет получать события изменения буфера.